# Parallel GIS with `future`

Tags: r, gis, r-sf, r-raster, furrr

I noticed that when loading `furrr` after `raster`, I am warned that `values` is masked:

```
The following object is masked from ‘package:raster’:

    values
```

I'm not 100% convinced that is the issue, but I am struggling to run `raster::extract` on `sf` objects

```
library(raster)
library(sf)
p <- shapefile(system.file("external/lux.shp", package="raster"))
s <- as(p, "sf")
r <- raster(p, ncol=100, nrow=100)
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)
```

I can extract just fine

```
raster::extract(r, s)
```

but when I parallelize (version 1) I get an error:

```
library(furrr)
plan(strategy = "multiprocess", workers =2)

future_map(1:2, function(extr){
  raster::extract(r,s)
})
```

one weird thing is that it seems to work ok with `sp` type objects (version 2)

```
u<-as(s, "Spatial")

future_map(1:2, function(extr){
  raster::extract(r,u)
})
```

Besides just switching between `sf` and `SpatialPointsDataFrame`, how can I get the "version 1" code working?

Comment: It seems likely to me that the fix is in here somewhere https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future/vignettes/future-4-issues.html

Comment: Have you tried calling `values` from the raster package explicitly: `raster::values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)` ?

Comment: @mrhellmann, do you mind spelling that out a bit more? Looks like a helpful suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workers aren't loading the `sf` package. Use `.options = furrr_options(packages = "sf")`.

### Reproducing the issue:

```
future_map(1:2, function(x){
  raster::extract(r,s)
})
#> Error in as(from, "Spatial"): no method or default for coercing "sf" to "Spatial"
```

### Solution:

```
future_map(1:2, .options = furrr_options(packages = "sf"), function(x){
  raster::extract(r,s)
})
```

Comment: This works! Thanks. Is the issue that this solves the masked `values` function, or potentially something more subtle?

Comment: You're welcome! What error were you getting before? When I tried to reproduce your issue, I got the error in my answer ("no method for coercing sf to sp"). Loading `sf` fixes that. I am not 100%, but that suggests to me it was just an issue with workers not loading the necessary packages.

Comment: I was getting the same error. I find that `furrr::future_map` usually just loads packages to the cluster, any guesses for what leads to failure in this specific case?

Comment: That was my impression too. I'm not sure. Perhaps there is some "nonexportable object" involved? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future/vignettes/future-4-non-exportable-objects.html

Comment: Nice. I won't dig into this but maybe @HenrikB will :-)